# Filter second Column when I select row in first Column in UIPickerView

Tags: filter, uipickerview

I have got two columns in pickerview. 
In first column there are three values: All, Fruits and Vegetables. 
In second column there are some values: Apple, Carrot, Celery, Cherry, Pear, Tomato.

At the first time I would like to see All in first column and all elements in second column.
But when I choose Fruits in first column as soon as I'dd like to see Apple, Cherry and Pear, in second column.
Is it possible?

Thanks a lot, especially who can post an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is Possible
as your example you just do following steps

1) make dictionary that have multiple array mean like this

```
 mainArray =[ NSMutableArray new]; // for 1st column value
[mainArray addObject:@"All"];
[mainArray addObject:@"Fruites"];
[mainArray addObject:@"Vegetables"];

NSMutableArray *DummyArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[DummyArray addObject:@"Apple"];
[DummyArray addObject:@"Mango"];
[DummyArray addObject:@"Cherry"];
[DummyArray addObject:@"Table"];
[DummyArray addObject:@"Chair"];
[DummyArray addObject:@"Pear"];
[DummyArray addObject:@"Tomato"];


mainDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[mainDict setValue:DummyArray   forKey:@"All"];

NSMutableArray *DummyArrayF = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[DummyArrayF addObject:@"Apple"];
[DummyArrayF addObject:@"Mango"];
[DummyArrayF addObject:@"Cherry"];
[mainDict setValue:DummyArrayF   forKey:@"Fruites"];


NSMutableArray *DummyArrayV = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[DummyArrayV addObject:@"Pear"];
[DummyArrayV addObject:@"Tomato"];
[mainDict DummyArrayV   forKey:@"Vegetables"];

selectValue = @"All";
```

here 'selectValue' show which

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
      return  2;
}
```

// returns the # of rows in each component..

```
  - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
switch (component) {

    case 0:
        return 3;
        break;

        case 1:
        return [[mainDict valueForKey:selectValue] count];
        break;

     }
    return 0;
}

  - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
switch (component) {
    case 0:
        return mainArray[row];
        break;

    case 1:
        return [mainDict valueForKey:selectValue][row];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return @"";
}

  - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
 switch (component) {
    case 0:
        selectValue = mainArray[row];
        [pickerView1 reloadAllComponents];

        break;

    default:
        break;
}

 }
```

if any question feel free to ask thanks